# Discord JS V11 BAN COMMAND

Tags: javascript, discord

Hello I have a ban command. Also I have a error. This is a code
I want solve. But I don't.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    komut: "ban",  
    açıklama: "", 
    kategori: "moderasyon", 
    alternatifler: ["!ban", "!yasakla"], 
    kullanım: "!ban", 
    yetki: "BAN_MEMBERS"
}

module.exports.baslat = (message) => {

// if(!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS"])) return message.channel.send("Ban atabilmek için yetkili olman gerek!")

let banMember = message.mention.members.first() || message.guild.member.get(args[0])
if(banMember) return message.channel.send("Lütfen banlamak istediğiniz kişiyi etiketleyin!")

let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
if (!reason) reason = "Lütfen bir sebep belirtiniz!"

// if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS" , "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("Bu komutu kullanmak için yetkim yok")

message.delete()

banMember.send(`Merhaba, iyi günler dilerim. ${message.guild.name} adlı sunucudan ${reason} sebebiyle banlandın.`).then(() =>
message.guild.ban(banMember, {days : 1 , reason : reason})).catch(err => console.log(err))

message.channel.send(`**${banMember.user.tag}** banlandı.`)

let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setColor("RED")
.setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Modlogs`, message.guild.iconURL)
.addField("Moderasyon :", "ban")
.addField("Kişi : ", banMember.user.username)
.addField("Banlayan Admin :", message.author.username)
.addField("Sebep : ", reason)
.addField("Date :", message.createdAt.toLocaleString())

    let sChannel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === "ban-log")
    sChannel.send({embed:embed})
};
```

This is a terminal error :

```
(node:16116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports.baslat (C:\Users\RYZEN\Desktop\U4 BOT\komutlar\moderasyon\ban.js:16:33)
    at AdvancedClient.<anonymous> (C:\Users\RYZEN\Desktop\U4 BOT\node_modules\discordjs-advanced\src\client.js:549:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:16116) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16116) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Please help me

Okey, don't see a

module.exports = {
komut: "ban",
açıklama: "",
kategori: "moderasyon",
alternatifler: ["!ban", "!yasakla"],
kullanım: "!ban",
yetki: "BAN_MEMBERS"
}

Note : I change members and users. Bot don't work again.

(Sorry for my bad english :) )

Answer (score 1):

You are using `message.mention.members.first()` but it should be `mentions` -

```js
message.mentions.members.first()
```

Comment: ```(node:12324) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined``` 

Don't work

Comment: it is beacuase your Guild cache is empty to fix this follow this answer -https://stackoverflow.com/a/65277312/14200419