# Can't reach members

Tags: javascript, discord.js

this is my code for displaying members in a role. But when i call this command for a role that has a lot of members in, it only returns my name. How i can fix it? V12

```
let role;

if(message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[0])) {
    role    = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[0]);
    if(!role)
        return message.reply("I can't find this role!");
} else {
    let choosenRole = args.slice(0).join(" ");
    if(!choosenRole)
        return message.reply("Please type a role name to check.");

    role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === choosenRole);
    if(!role)
        return message.reply("I can't find this role!");

}

    let inrole = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#09ba87")
    .setAuthor(`${role.name}(${role.members.size})`)
    .setDescription(`\n・` + role.members.map(m => m.user.username + "#" + m.user.discriminator).join("\n・"))

    let m = await message.channel.send(inrole);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there your issue is because of recent gateway changes of the Discord Api that the `Guild` cache is empty , you need to enable the intents here is a fix for you -

- Head over to [Discord Developers Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications/)
- Choose your application
- Inside the `bot` section if you scroll a little bit down , you will see a section named `Privileged Gateway Intents`
- Enable the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` and restart the bot and you will find your cache is not limited to small number!

If this still dosent work try fetching all guild members - `message.guild.members.fetch()`
Learn more about intents at [Discord.js](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html)