# Listing every user that has a specific Discord Role

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm looking to run a command that lists everyone that has a specified Discord Role [using the command, I will provide the ID for said role in question] Documentation and googling around seems to be a dead end as Discord updated their function. The biggest issue is that the current method I have here only works if the user is online/has typed recently and they will be stored in the cache along with their roles. I was hoping to have one that lists the roles no matter what.

```js
case 'rolecheck':
        var roleneeded = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');
    if(message.content.startsWith("$rolecheck")){
          const ListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle('Users with this role:')
                            .setDescription(message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleneeded[1]).members.map(m=>m.user.tag).join('\n'));
                    }

  break;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try enabling the intents from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65277312/14200419)
and fetch all the members while logging or the alternative thing would be fetching members -

```js
message.guild.members.fetch({cache : false}).then(members=>{
members.filter(x=>x.roles.cache.has("id")); //this would be your member array 
})
```

> Note this method has the potential to throw an error `Error [GUILD_MEMBERS_TIMEOUT]: Members didn't arrive in time.` if you don't have `Guild Members` intent enabled

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`message.guild.roles.fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch) method like this:

```js
case 'rolecheck':
    const roleneeded = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');
    if (message.content.startsWith("$rolecheck")) {
        message.guild.roles.fetch(roleneeded[1], true, true).then(role => {
            const ListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle('Users with this role:')
                .setDescription(role.members.map(m => m.user.tag).join('\n'));
            message.channel.send(ListEmbed);
        }).catch(console.error)
    }
break;
```

The `fetch(roleneeded[1], true, true)` makes discord.js get the latest info from the API without using the cache.

Comment: Unfortuntely this didn't work. I had no error, but no embed popped up either.

Comment: Yes, because you need to actually send the embed

Comment: @blackelonmusk I've edited the post, use the new code to send the embed

Comment: Thanks, it was really late at night when I looked at that and put it in originally. So this is working, but it's behaving like the original code for some reason. Still only listing users that have recently typed. I assigned a role to my second account and friend on the server, and it won't show they have that role unless they type still. Maybe it's just how Discord is now since V11 -> V12? @sportzpikachu

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure... Perhaps API lag? Haven't used discord.js in a while, so I don't know about the new update.